# Какое свойство у тега <p> отвечает за то, что бы текст начинался от самого края блока?

Tags: html, css, html5, scss

Мне надо сформировать html страницу из файла фотошопа.

Данные я все получаю.
Но у текстовых блоков есть отступ от начала блока. Это не padding.
По этому у меня происходит смещение текста на эту величину.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне сделать так, что бы текст начинался от самого начала блока ?

Дополнение:

Если я размер шрифта ставлю 200 px увеличивается и этот отступ

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Свойства css:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы страницу в браузере открываете? в хроме к примеру нажмите F12 и выберите этот элемент и посмотрите ВСЕ его свойства (включая унаследованные от родителей) или хотя бы сюда код выложите, чтобы посмотреть

Comment: Прикрепил картинку. Я специально консоль на весь экран сделал.
Это все свойства css какие есть

Comment: Вероятно, это просто особенность шрифта? Тогда может помочь только какой-нибудь `margin-left: -0.12em;`

Comment: Вот я об этом же подумал...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наконец-то удалось разобраться в чем дело:

во-первых при шрифтах с засечками данный эффект может не наблюдаться, например Times New Roman:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но стоит изменить шрифт на иной (без засечек), например на Tahoma, то получается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Значит дело скорее всего в шрифте или в том, как отрисовываются шрифты разных типов.

Поэтому надо смотреть в сторону "щели/пробела перед первой буквой текста"

И поиск дал эту тему:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28809771/left-space-on-first-letter-css

и псевдоэлемента `:first-letter`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter

Comment: Спасибо. Это гениальный ответ !

Answer (score 0):

```
text-align: left; /* текст от левого края блока */
padding: 0; /* отступы внутри блока равны 0 */
margin: 0; /* отступы снаружи блока равны 0 */
```

еще могут быть

```
left: 0;
top: 0;
```

еще может оказаться граница цвета фона, ее тоже убрать надо бы тогда

```
border: none;
```

Comment: Padding -а  и margin -а  нет. text-align left.
Это что то связанное с отступами самого шрифта

Comment: а вы уверены, что нет, ведь не обязательно `padding` делать для конкретно элемента `<p>`, можно сделать через его родителя, к примеру `div * {padding: 5px;}`

Comment: Это может быть

user agent stylesheet
display: block;
    margin-block-start: 1em;
    margin-block-end: 1em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;

Но я их переопределил и не помогло.

Нет других стилей.

Есть свойство line-height:  - оно высоту блока определяет.
Надо то же самое только для левой и правой части

Comment: @Sergey, вы css можете свой ставить? если да, то попробуйте жестко установить `padding`, `margin` как `padding: 0px !important`, `margin: 0px !important`

Comment: Это не padding и не margin. Ставил я.

Comment: @Sergey, а код глянуть можно хоть в каком-то виде, чтобы можно было бы более точно сказать?

Comment: У меня нет кода. Это фактически 
<div><slot name="xxx"></slot></div>
<p slot="xxx">text</p>

Я сейчас генерирую как раз html. А js данные с psd берёт. Я позднее отдельно html сделаю, что бы точно понять что это такое.

Comment: @Sergey, но вы же просматриваете страницу в браузере? выбираете в консоли разработчика (F12 для хрома) этот элемент и начинаете отключать стили и смотрите, что происходит - когда добьетесь удаления этого свободного места, то поймете что отвечает за него

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113722/discussion-between-zhihar-and-sergey).